# How do I enable Vm protection in my virtual network on Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, security, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azureportal

I have created one virtual network on Azure portal, I wish to enable VM protection for that, any idea how that can be done?

So I have one Virtual network on Azure portal that have one subnet inside it, that subnet consists of a Virtual Machine and for that subnet I have defined one network security group(NSG). Now according to Azure API while making a call to get meta data for virtual network I should get a property "properties.enableVmProtection boolean Indicates if VM protection is enabled for all the subnets in the virtual network." I am unable to view that property while making the call to the API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/virtualnetworks/listall

Comment: Please elaborate what features you're looking for to protect your VM.

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara

So I have one Virtual network on Azure portal that have one subnet inside it, that subnet consists of a Virtual Machine and for that subnet I have defined one network security group(NSG). Now according to Azure API while making a call to get meta data for virtual network I should get a property 

"properties.enableVmProtection 
boolean
Indicates if VM protection is enabled for all the subnets in the virtual network." 
I am unable to view that property while making the call to the API

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/virtualnetworks/listall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enableVmProtection` is a legacy flag that has been now been deprecated and replaced with `enableDdosProtection`. This is why the API no longer returns this property.

More info in this GitHub issue: [Function of --vm-protection #14059](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14059)

Coming to `enableDdosProtection`, this property indicates if DDoS protection is enabled for all the protected resources in the virtual network. It requires a DDoS protection plan associated with the resource.

The steps to enable DDoS protection for an existing virtual network are detailed in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/manage-ddos-protection#enable-ddos-protection-for-an-existing-virtual-network) article.

Comment: It's worth noting DDoS Protection Plans cost $2,944/month so you most likely won't want to enable it unless you actually need DDoS protection.